# React Native i18n-js: Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, internationalization

I have a React Native project that was using [i18n-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-js) older version (3.8.0), so I decided upgrade this package on my project.

This is the new code:
`src/i18n/src/locale/index.ts`

```
import {I18n} from 'i18n-js';
import en from './en-US';
import pt from './pt-BR';

const translations = {en, 'pt-BR': pt};
type TranslationsTypes = keyof typeof translations;

const i18n = new I18n(translations);

export default i18n;

export const translate = (key: string) => i18n.t(key);
```

And this is a sample how I use:

```
import {translate} from 'i18n/src/locale';

<Text style={{color: '#DDDDDD', marginLeft: 5}}>
   {translate('text_1')}
</Text>
```

But when I start my React Native project, I get this warning:

```
Require cycle: node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/index.js -> node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/formatNumber.js -> node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

Is this a i18n-js package problem, or did I something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As temporary fix:

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
'Require cycle: node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/index.js -> node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/formatNumber.js -> node_modules/i18n-js/dist/import/helpers/index.js\n',
]);
```

Fixed in https://github.com/fnando/i18n/pull/35